# How to setup new zend framework in netbeans on Ubuntu

Tags: zend-framework, ubuntu, netbeans

I reached up to PHP Frameworks by (New PHP Project) > (Name and Location) > (Run Configuration) > (PHP Frameworks).

Now when I tried to select Zend PHP Framework, Netbeans is saying the error no zend script selected.

How can I configure Zend Framework on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [manual of Zend_Tool](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.tool.framework.clitool.html) on how to set it up. And then use

```
zf create project myproject
```